# Magento individual discount for inner product of bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, totals, bundle-product, grand-total

Hello I have one question regarding bundle product in magento

Let me take one example to be clear

Suppose I have one bundle product named "bundle_test" and their child product which are simple product named "bundle_child_1", "bundle_child_2", "bundle_child_3"

Now I have work to do is If some one is selecting "bundle_test" then I need to set 10% discount on "bundle_child_1" 50% on "bundle_child_2" and price will for that bundle will be calculated dynamically and the product will display like

suppose "bundle_child_1" has price 100 "bundle_child_2" has price 200

then product will **bundle_test** bundle_child_1: 100 (-10) bundle_child_2: 200 (-100) bundle_child_3: 300

subtotal: 600 discount: -110 grandtotal: 490

Answer (score 2):

As i understand the Question you can do this with "Catalog Price Rules".
Add a New Catalog Price Rule and configure the it like this:

```
Condition: Add SKU with value of SKU from "bundle_child_1"
Actions: - Apply: By Percentage of the original Price
         - Discount Amount: 10.0000
         - Enable Discount to Subproducts: No
         - Stop further Rules Processing: No
```

Click "Save and Apply".
As Result the price of the product "bundle_test_1" will get a discount of 10% and also the parent does.

For "bundle_test_2" and "bundle_test_3" you do exactly the same but change the the SKU and Discount Amount value to the Amount you want you give.

Comment: I would love you give one down point to your answer as you are suggesting such an option which is not present in magento

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little misleading, because it doesn't explain that if you wanted to also be able to sell the bundle items individually, you would have to create new products.

What's missing in Magento is the ability to set a discount at the bundle item level that allows the system to dynamically calculate the bundle item price based on the base price of the simple product and the discount.